Normal p-complement exercise (Problem 5C.1 Isaacs' Finite Group Theory)
I have a question about the following problem [Finite Group Theory, Martin Isaacs, Chapter 5]:
Show that Burnside's normal p-complement theorem is a consequence of Theorem 5.18.
I report the two theorems in question:
Theorem (Burnside): Let $ P \in Syl_{p}(G) $, where $G$ is a finite group, and suppose $ P \subseteq Z(N_{G}(P)) $. Then $G$ has a normal $p$-complement.
Theorema 5.18: Let $P$ be an abelian Sylow $p$-subgroup of a finite group $G$. Then
$$ G'\cap P \cap \textbf{Z}(N_{G}(P))=1. $$
I report my reasoning:
Let $ P \in Syl_{p}(G) $. If $P \subseteq Z(N_{G}(P)) $, then $ P \cap Z(N_{G}(P))=P $, and hence $ G' \cap P \cap \textbf{Z}(N_{G}(P))=G' \cap P=1 $. Let $ v:G \rightarrow P/P'$ the transfer homomorphism, I observe that $ G/\ker(v) \cong v(G) \leq P/P' $ and $ P/P' $ is abelian. Then $ G/\ker(v) $ is abelian and hence $ G'\subseteq \ker(v) $. Now, by Lemma 5.11 from M.Isaacs Finite Group Theory, I know that $ |G:\ker(v)|=|P:P \cap \ker(v)|\leq |P:P \cap G'|=|P:1|=|P| $.
Can it be concluded that $ \ker(v) $ is the normal $ p $-complement of $ G $?

You are supposed to deduce that $G$ has a normal $p$-complement directly from $G' \cap P = 1$, without further use of the transfer homomorphism or other results from the book. This is not difficult. If $G' \cap P = 1$ then $G'$ is a $p'$-group. So consider $G/G'$.

I get it, thank you. $ G^{′} $ is a $ p^{′} $-group so $ |G^{′}| $ isn't divisible by $ p $, that is $ p \not | |G^{′}|=|G|/|G:G^{′}| $ and as $ p | |G| $ then $ p | |G:G^{'}| $. So, $ G^{′} $ is a $ p $-complement of $ G $.

Not quite. $G'$ itself needn't be a $p$-complement, but it is contained in a $p$-complement.

Right, thank you.
